# rDNS lookup process

Tags: dns, reverse

I understand the forward DNS lookup process. Essentially each domain has one or more authoritative name servers, and these authoritative name servers are ultimately responsible for answering the question what the ip address is for the domain name looked up.

However, I don't understand how the reverse DNS lookup works. Essentially I don't understand who is the authoritative rDNS name server? Normally whoever provided the ip address? When I dig -x `a.b.c.d`, how does the dig program know where to look for the authoritative rDNS server to get the domain name for the ip address `a.b.c.d`?

Thanks,
Elgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the `a.b.c.d` netblock is also the owner of `c.b.a.in-addr.arpa.` The reverse DNS query looks up a `PTR` record for `d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa.` internally. (Still not too many years ago, you had to perform this manipulation yourself; it wasn't built into `dig` and friends.)

There are semi-obvious problems with this when the delegated netblock is smaller than a /24; then the upstream will have to handle rDNS somehow. It's not too uncommon that they will provide approximate or outright incorrect information in this scenario. (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317 proposes a solution, but it is nowhere near ubiquitous in practice.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup has a much more detailed treatment if you require details.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. One thing I still don't understand is how this happens. When I do `dig -x a.b.c.d`, how does it determine which server exactly is the authoritative rDNS server to answer this question, as opposed to another fake server?

Comment: Normal DNS delegation and resolution; `in-addr.arpa.` tells you the authoritative source for `a.in-addr.arpa`, which in turn points you to the authority for `b.a.in-addr.arpa.` etc.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I started to understand now. However, can you make it a little bit more specific? What is in-addr.arpa? Where does it physically or logically reside? What if my immediately dns server happened to have a ptr record for this ip, but what if it points to a fake domain?

Comment: If you don't trust your local resolver, you're dead already.  The [root servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server) have the delegation information for the [`arpa.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.arpa) TLD just like they have for `com.`, `net.`, `uk.`, etc.

Comment: So can I understand the d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa as another tree of domain names, starting from the tld `arpa`. It works in the similar way as A records work?

Comment: They are virtually identical in practice but they are called `PTR` records when what they contain isn't an address.